# Upgraded MySQL from 5.1 to 5.5, running into PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: mysql, upgrade

I have my website database running on another machine (MySQL DB) where v5.5 is installed. The current machine (with PhP / Drupal) is on 5.1.

Upgraded MySQL on my current machine from v5.1 to v5.5 so I could have both Drupal and MySQL on the same box (done all the hygiene steps - mysql_upgrade, my.cnf configured correctly).

MySQL grant privileges is also given to the resp DB users. There are no errors in MySQL log (eliminated all of them).

The particular function worked perfectly fine with the earlier setup (DB on another machine with 5.5), however I am running into few problems in the current setup. See below.

```
    PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
    1305 FUNCTION xxx_system.gen_stat_as_due_ors does not exist: 
    SELECT gen_stat_as_due_ors(:xx_number, :assigned_date); Array ( [:xx_number] => 5229 
    [:assigned_date] => 2013-04-08 00:00:00 ) in xxx_utils_get_report_rep4a1() 
    (line 403 of /home/xxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/custom/xxx_utils/xxx_utils.reports.inc).
```

Linux 2.6.32-042stab076.8 x86_64

Have been searching desperately on my machine and over the internet for a solution (2 days now!!!) no luck!

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check the user's grants. I think the user hasn't been given `EXECUTE` privileges to the `gen_stat_as_due_ors` procedure.

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON /*./* TO 'user'@'*' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; This is what I had used, I guess that covers it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that your function is not existing on your new host, you get an error `1305` "function does not exist" here, verify that your function is existing on the new host. I strongly doubt, that you have lack of permissions. In case of missing `EXECUTE` privilege you would see an error `1370` "command denied to user". You can check if the function is present by issuing: `SHOW FUNCTION STATUS`;

So in your case i would suggest that you check your dumpfiles for the routine, the option `--routines` is false by default. Therefore routines (functions, stored procedures) won´t be included in your dump. You can migrate the missing routines by simply dumping your old data with mysqldump, something like `mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db yourdatabasename > routines.sql` will do the trick. Please consult the manpages before, i was not testing above command.

Of course you can alkso manually add the missing functions if you have the necessary statements.

Comment: Savior! Checked the dump, and guess what missing routines. Thank you! Looks like I cant vote, newbie...